# How to add multiple checked records

Tags: javascript, marketing-cloud

We have a loop that adds multiple records to a form allowing them to select various options. How can we post the values that are checked for each selected option?

```
        <fieldset id="radio">
        <label>Select.... </label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="cancel" value="all" />
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset id="actions">
            <input type="hidden" name="AppointmentID" value="%%=v(@Value)=%%" />
            <input type="submit" value="Cancel" class="button-green transparent" />
        </fieldset>
      </form>



    $('#reschedule').submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   // 1. Validate form
    var moarMsg = '';
    var isValid = true;
    $('#reschedule .required').each(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('error-input');
        if( this.value == '' && $(this).is(":visible") ) {
            $(this).addClass('error-input');
            isValid = false;
        }
    });
    //radio buttons - check if we actually have them before validating
    if($('#radio').length) {
        if($("input[type='radio']:checked").length == 0) {
            //alert('no radio buttons checked');
            var moarMsg = ' Please let us know if this applies to one or all appointments.';
            isValid = false;
        }
    }

    if(isValid == true) {
    // 2. Submit form
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: form.attr('action'),
            data: $('#reschedule').serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
                if(response.success) {
                    //redirect to thank you
                    //var newUrl =  $(location).attr('href') + '/thankyou'; 
                    //window.location = newUrl;
                    window.location.href = 'url';
                } else {
                    //show error msg
                    $('.error-box').html(response.errors[0]);
                    $('.error-box').show();
                    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "fast");
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had to do something similar.  What I did was create a bunch of hidden fields on the landing page corresponding to the fields in the extension.  When the user hit submit I would run a bunch of Jquery before the page POSTed, to populate said hidden fields.   Instead of posting to a thank you page, however, I would post to a processing page, consisting of a mix of AMPscript and SSJS.  The SSJS was there to give me "try- catch" functionality, the AMPscript did all the heavy lifting.  I would grab the posted hidden field values and use UpsertData to put those into the DE, and if there was no exception thrown, THEN I would redirect to  the thank you page.  Otherwise, I would redirect to some kind of error page.

Like so:

```
%%[  

VAR @IsValid, @Result

]%%

<script runat="server" language="javascript" >
    Platform.Load("Core","1"); //This loads SSJS engine
//do more ssjs stuff, 
try
{

</script>

%%[
UpsertData(your, fields, go, here)  
Redirect(@yourThankYouLink)
]%%

<script runat="server" language="javascript" >
} catch {
</script>
%%[
Redirect(@yourErrorLink)
]%%
<script runat="server" language="javascript" >
}

</script>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Could you provide a little more background on "try-catch" functionality. Haven't had any experience with that before and my searches are all returning unrelated topics to this context. Thanks

Comment: Sure.  Have a look at http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/server_side_javascript/.  I will modify my answer as well.

Comment: How does the upsert only use the selected values from the form? We want to upsert the checked values to one location and have all the unchecked values upsert to a separate DE.

Comment: Also, the page is working now in that it adds a single record to the DE on submit.

Comment: I would suggest you build part of the UpsertData string client side with JQuery (essentially the name-value pairs), one for each DE, and store them in a hidden field.  Your processing page would then get each of those hidden fields and call UpsertDate on the processing page.